# Groovy/GSP redirect around controller

Tags: grails, controllers

I have a web application that I am trying not to recompile since there is little documentation and the environment is a little sensitive.

With that in mind, all I am trying to do is hijack the authentication mechanism to redirect to one of a couple replacement websites. To that end, there is an authentication service and an authentication controller. The website redirects to /auth/login when the user comes unauthenticated.

In the views folder I have built an alternative /auth/login_new.gsp and from there can authenticate the user and get a redirection back to /auth/redirect.gsp at some frequency but not 100%. That redirect page takes a value from the DB and redirects the user to the correct follow on website. When I run authentication from /auth/login, the site ignores the redirect request to /auth/redirect.gsp.

I had set the show pages for all the different controllers to  window.location.href="/auth/redirect.gsp" but I can't get it to go there 100%. I have also reset the layout/domain.gsp file to gut the other functionality of the site and script redirect as well. I was getting errors with duplicate redirect attempts, but now I just go to a dead/gutted homepage...

Any suggestions on how I can dodge the recompile?

Thanks
Leif

Comment: I assume this is grails?

Comment: Yes, it is an older implementation on Groovy 1.6.SO, I was able to figure a way out by shifting from redirects to groovy {} and goes through each pages expected load conditions to find a way around it.

Thanks Leif

Comment: "I have a web application that I am trying not to recompile". It seems that you want to cache the output of gsp's, am I right?